# Using wygwam with readmore under contentelements

Tags: wygwam, content-elements

```
{content_a}
    {wygwam:excerpt}
        {value}
    {/wygwam}
    {wygwam:extended}
        {value}
    {/wygwam}
{/content_a}
```

I wanted to have a readmore button instead, The code above outputs everything from the entry id
Can you help me?

Legend:
Content_a = contentelement field
Wygwam = wygwam under contentelement field

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to go about this that I can think of.

### Option A

You can have **separate Content Element code** for the listing page vs the single-entry page:

Listing page:

```
{content_a}
    {wygwam:excerpt}
        {value}
    {/wygwam}
    <a href="#">Read More...</a>
{/content_a}
```

Single-entry page:

```
{content_a}
    {wygwam} // shows the entirety of the Wygwam field
        {value}
    {/wygwam}

    // Also include the other field types:
    {image} ... {/image}
    {video} ... {/video}
{/content_a}
```

### Option B

You can have an entirely separate Wygwam field (called `content_summary` here) for the summary/excerpt, leaving the Content Elements field dedicated to the full article content:

Listing page:

```
{content_summary}
<a href="#">Read More...</a>
```

Single-entry page:

```
{content_a}
    {wygwam}
        {value}
    {/wygwam}

    // Also include the other field types:
    {image} ... {/image}
    {video} ... {/video}
{/content_a}
```